# Changed files are not recognized while debugging after restart project under Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat

I know it's kinda popular question and it has a lot of suggestions already, but I have tried all of them, and it hasn't helped me. Maybe I am missing something ?

So here is my Run/debug configuration:[image]

As you can see I already set up 'On 'Update' action' and 'On frame action', and it still not working as expected.

While debug I am getting next warnings:

[image]

I am also add new attributes at context.xml file:

```
<Resources antiResourceLocking="false" cachingAllowed="false" />
```

Tomcat version is: 7.0.47

My changes applying only after maven `clean install` command, that builds me a war file and I put this war file into tomcatHome/webapps folder.

Could someone please suggest any solutions ?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is: I should rebuild the jar file where I am changing the code (because this changes are not inside web app project) and then I should update tomcat using ctrl+F10.